# add legend texts and a line legend in R

Tags: r, legend

I have a plot in R made by base graphics, and I wanna add some legends. The first two rows of the legend are only texts: for example

```
Data is from xx
Model is yy
```

The third row I wanna add to the legend and **align properly with the first two rows** is a **dotted blue** line with legend `y=0.05`. Thus, what I want in the end is

```
Data is from xx
Model is yy
---- y = 0.05
```

Is there any convenient way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: two legends with titles?

Comment: @mnel: maybe not... I have title already; these information should go to the legend part

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482113/having-subsections-in-a-legend-of-a-plot-in-r/15489430#15489430 (thelatemail's answer)